# Saved Searches Conditional HTML Formatting

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to highlight/indicate individual fields within a saved search column based on a certain criteria. I don't want to highlight the specific row as that will highlight the entire row and not just the single column.

The rudimentary code I have now is

```
CASE WHEN {custbody487} = 'On Time' 
THEN {custbody487}
ELSE CASE WHEN {custbody487} = 'On Hold' 
THEN {custbody487}
ELSE CASE WHEN {custbody487} = 'Late' 
THEN {custbody487}
END END END
```

How do I conditionally highlight only a specific column? I want to highlight On Time as green, On Hold as blue, etc. But I only want to highlight the text in that specific column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add HTML formatting to saved searches.

Make sure you're using Formula(text) under results. 
Here's what the above code looks like highlighted.

```
 CASE WHEN {custbody487} = 'On Time' 
    THEN '<span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">' || {custbody487} || '</span>' 
    ELSE CASE WHEN {custbody487} = 'Late' 
    THEN '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">' || {custbody487} || '</span>' 
    ELSE CASE WHEN {custbody487} = 'On Hold' 
    THEN '<span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">' || {custbody487} || '</span>' 
END END END
```

Be advised that searches saved this way will not keep their HTML formatting upon export to PDF or CSV. It will be formatted as plain text.