# NetSuite Saved Search using formula (numeric) with html for formatting

Tags: html, sql, oracle, netsuite

I need to make a saved search which sum's all quotes made per sales rep by month and highlight certain cells based on sum amount of numeric formula.

This is what I have now (it's a Saved Transaction Search)

Criteria
Type is Quotation
Main Line is True
Sales Rep is any of **,**,...
Date is after start of this year.

Result
Sales Rep Group
Formula (Numeric)   SUM   `CASE WHEN to_char({custbody_Lastupdateddate}, 'MM')= '01', then 1 else 0 end.`
Formula (Numeric)   SUM   `CASE WHEN to_char({custbody_Lastupdateddate}, 'MM')= '02', then 1 else 0 end.`
Formula (Numeric)   SUM   `CASE WHEN to_char({custbody_Lastupdateddate}, 'MM')= '02', then 1 else 0 end.` 
...This continues until May.

I now need to highlight the cell based on quantity of quotes per rep per month. I have dabbled with HTML but cannot seem to figure out how to write the formula to accomplish this.

Does anyone have any feedback? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010836/saved-searches-conditional-html-formatting/55010837#55010837

Answer (score 1):

You can return HTML from your formula, using Formula(text).  The trick is to move your aggregate functions inside the formula, and simply use `MINIMUM` as the Summary Type.  The following formula should get you close to what you want:

```
CASE
   WHEN
      COUNT(
      CASE
         WHEN
            to_char({trandate}, 'MM') = '01' 
         THEN
            {internalid} 
      END
) > 50  --more than 50 quotes in the month should be green
   THEN
     '<div style="color:white;background-color:green;">' || 
COUNT(
      CASE
         WHEN
            to_char({trandate}, 'MM') = '01' 
         THEN
            {internalid} 
      END
) || '</div>' 
   ELSE   --the rest will be red
      '<p style="color:white;background-color:red;">' || COUNT(
      CASE
         WHEN
            to_char({trandate}, 'MM') = '01' 
         THEN
            {internalid} 
      END
) || '</p>' 
END
```

You'll see I used `<div>` and `<p>` tags - both work.  `<span>` and `<table>` tags work too; what you end up using might depend on other specific display characteristics I won't go into here.

Comment: Thank you for the quick recommendations; this was exactly what I was looking for. Also, I noticed I was referencing an incorrect field and once changed to "trandate", I was seeing the results I was hoping to see. Thanks again!

Comment: One more question: when I click on the sales reps name to view more detail, the group by "minimum do not show up. Do I need to add any summary groupings?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question; could you rephrase and give more detail?

Comment: My apologies. Please disregard my last question. Thank you for your help!